# $t\mapsto\tau(\omega)\land t$ continuous?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $T\subseteq \overline{\mathbb R}$ be an intervall and $\tau:\Omega\to \overline T$ a stopping time. (I don't think it is necessary to mention that $\tau$ is a stopping time but I am not sure).

> For fixed $\omega \in \Omega$, do we have that the mapping $$t\mapsto\tau(\omega)\land t$$
> is continuous? $(t \in T)$

Can there arise any problems if $\tau(\omega)\in \overline T\setminus T?$

Comment: yes of course. If $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then so is $f\wedge g$.

Comment: @surb And $\tau(\omega)$ is a constant, right?

Comment: yes. $\ \ \ \ \ \ $